# how to remove a value from select box after being selected

Tags: jquery, select, csv, jquery-plugins, tags

**What I'm trying to do is upload a CSV file then count the columns of the file, then arrange the columns according to their content.**

**Ex: there are 3 columns on the CSV file the user will now determine the content of the column so it can be properly uploaded to the database.**

**How can i use a select option to fill out input boxes, after the user picks the value it will be disabled from the select box.**

[image]

**the select box will contain certain values.**

[image]

**after selection the value will now be disabled or removed until unselected from the previous select box.**

[image]

similar to the **[Jquery Tag's Multi Selector](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select)** http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select

but it is going to be distributed to every line created from the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/rM88C/2/

It should allow you to add an indeterminate amount of "Jquery Chosen" dropdowns and and have any selected value "disabled" across all dropdowns with the same class name. I've provided a multi-select version, but converting it to a single select version for your purposes should be trivial.

Javascript code provided below but check out Fiddle first

```
// get selects for later use
var selects = $('.myChosen');

// whenever the selection changes, either disable or enable the 
// option in the other selects
selects.chosen().change(function() {
    var selected = [];

    // add all selected options to the array
    selects.find("option").each(function() {
        if (this.selected) {
            selected[this.value] = this;
        }
    })

    // disable or enable options
    .each(function() {

        // if the current option is already selected in another select disable it.
        // otherwise, enable it.
        this.disabled = selected[this.value] && selected[this.value] !== this;
    });

    // trigger the change event in the other "chosen" selects
    selects.trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```